# Issue with stylesheet after switching from IE to EDGE. Background color shifted

Tags: html, css, sql, microsoft-edge

I'm building a calendar dynamically with table elements (tr,td) combined together in SQL and then bound to a Repeater. The current day is highlighted by adding background-color to the number in a `<td>` cell. After switching from IE to EDGE that highlighted background is shifted in relation to the number.

[image]

This is how the html code is created in SQL:

```
COALESCE(PRETAG,'') + '<td style=text-align:center;column-width:52px;background-color:#'+ COALESCE(ColorCode,'FFFFFF') + ';>' 
                                          + Case WHEN DATEDIFF(day, date, getdate()) = 0 
                                                 THEN '<span class=highlight>&nbsp;'  
                                                 ELSE ''
                                                 END as PRETAG,
CAST(datepart(day, date) as nvarchar) + Case WHEN DATEDIFF(day, date, getdate()) = 0 
                                             THEN '&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>'
                                             ELSE ''
                                             END + '<br />' + CASE WHEN delta is Null THEN '&nbsp;'
                                                                   WHEN delta < 10 and delta > 0 THEN '0' 
                                                                   ELSE CAST(delta as NVARCHAR) END + CASE WHEN extra > 0 THEN '+' + CAST(extra as nvarchar) ELSE '' END as TAG
```

and this is how it is rendered in the browser:

```
<td style=text-align:center;column-width:52px;background-color:#C0C0C0;><span class=highlight>&nbsp;
        <a id="RepeaterKalendar_ctl183_ButtonSelect" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;RepeaterKalendar$ctl183$ButtonSelect&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="vertical-align:text-bottom;text-decoration:none">2&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><br />&nbsp;</a> 
        </td>
```

Anybody has a hint to solve this? I could live with it, but I'm a perfectionist.
Martin

Comment: It took my longer to document this, than to solve it. Sometimes writing a post gives the right hints. I just added verticle-align:top to the CSS Class highlight and that worked.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution to the issue. I suggest you post your solution as an answer for this thread and try to mark your own answer as an answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally could solve this by adding vertical-align:top to the css-class that I'm assigning the span element to that keeps the number for the day. This wasn't necessary under Internet Explorer; now with Edge for some reason it is. Interesting!